# netsh command returning unrecognized error, unknown reason

Tags: batch-file, block, rule, netsh

```
@echo off
@title Program Internet Disconnector
REM check for admin rights code was here but is too long for this post    
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
echo Press any key to Start
pause >nul
cls
set i=0
for %%x in (exe) do (
for /r %%a in (*.%%x) do (
set /a i+=1
set P!i!=%%~fdpa
set F!i!=%%~nxa
))
set y=0
:lock
set /a y+=1
if %y% gtr %i% (
goto Done)
set exec=!F%y%!
set path=!P%y%!
echo:
```

These values for the variables `exec` and `path`, return normally (i.e. `executable.exe` and `C:\`) just like they should:

```
echo %exec%
echo %path%
pause
```

Here though, the issue is that the netsh command returns the error 
`'netsh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="%exec%" dir=in action=block program="%path%" enable=yes
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="%exec%" dir=out action=block program="%path%" enable=yes
pause
goto lock
:Done
echo:
echo Press any key to exit...
Pause >nul
exit
```

What is the problem here as I cannot tell why this code is not just blocking the program and moving on. I've even used this code once before in a similar way without the bug. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps netsh is not installed on your PC. If you open the command line and type `netsh` do you get the `netsh>` prompt?

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` is a special variable - it contains a list of <kbd>;</kbd>-separated directories which are searched for an executable. When you change `path`, the executable netsh.exe can no longer be found.

Solution : don't attempt to use `path` as a user-variable (equally, any other variable listed when you issue a `set` command at the prompt.) - and others like `random`,`time`,`date` etc...

Comment: i knew that path was a "special variable" and yet even so it passes right over my head that it was in my code written exactly as path... *facepalm*. that was the issue, thanks!